# Nest.js Auth Guard JWT Authentication constantly returns 401 unauthorized

Tags: passport.js, nestjs, jwt, passport-jwt

Using Postman to test my endpoints, I am able to successfully "login" and receive a JWT token. Now, I am trying to hit an endpoint that supposedly has an `AuthGuard` to ensure that now that I am logged in, I can now access it.

However, it constantly returns `401 Unauthorized` even when presented the JWT token in Postman.

Here is my code:

**user.controller.ts**

```js
@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

  @UseGuards(AuthGuard())
  @Get()
  getUsers() {
    return this.usersService.getUsersAsync();
  }
}
```

**jwt.strategy.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: 'SuperSecretJWTKey',
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any, done: Function) {
    console.log('I AM HERE'); // this never gets called.
    const user = await this.authenticationService.validateUserToken(payload);

    if (!user) {
      return done(new UnauthorizedException(), false);
    }

    done(null, user);
  }
}
```

I have tried `ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('JWT')` as well but that does not work.

**authentication.module.ts**

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
    UsersModule,
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'SuperSecretJWTKey',
      signOptions: { expiresIn: 3600 },
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthenticationController],
  providers: [AuthenticationService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
  exports: [AuthenticationService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
})
export class AuthenticationModule {}
```

**authentication.controller.ts**

```js
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthenticationController {
  constructor(
    private readonly authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private readonly usersService: UsersService,
  ) {}

  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
  @Post('login')
  public async loginAsync(@Response() res, @Body() login: LoginModel) {
    const user = await this.usersService.getUserByUsernameAsync(login.username);

    if (!user) {
      res.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).json({
        message: 'User Not Found',
      });
    } else {
      const token = this.authenticationService.createToken(user);
      return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json(token);
    }
  }
}
```

In Postman, I am able to use my login endpoint to successfully login with the proper credentials and receive a JWT token. Then, I add an `Authentication` header to a GET request, copy and paste in the JWT token, and I have tried both "Bearer" and "JWT" schemes and both return `401 Unauthorized` as you can see in the images below.

[image]

[image]

I used the JWT.IO debugger, to check if there's anything wrong with my token and it appears correct:
[image]

I am at a lost as to what could be the issue here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem may be in your request from Postman. Try to create new request and be cautious what you place in headers.
If you are using bearer token place it in auth section, not in headers. Or place it in headers, not in auth section. Make a few experiments, it can help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that the `validate()` function in your JWT strategy is only called *after* successful validation of the JWT. If you are consistently getting a 401 response when trying to use the JWT then you can't expect this function to be called.

The `return` from the `validate()` method is injected into the request object of any operation that's guarded with JWT authentication.

I'm not sure about the `done()` function that you're calling, but here's a working `validate()` method from a current project of mine:

```js
async validate(payload: JwtPayload): Promise<User> {
  const { email } = payload
  const user = await this.authService.getActiveUser(email)

  if (!user) {
    throw new UnauthorizedException()
  }

  return user
}
```

It looks like you're on the right track in the desire to return a user. Be sure that's what `authenticationService.validateUserToken()` actually does.

In the strategy, `jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()` seems correct, and in Postman using Authorization header with `Bearer TOKEN` also looks correct.

Regarding your `authentication.controller.ts` file, be careful about using `@Request` and `@Response` objects directly within your controllers in NestJS. These access the underlying framework e.g. Express and are liable to bypass many of the features implemented by Nest. Refer to https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/request-lifecycle to see what you're skipping out on...

You can return objects and throw errors directly from a decorated controller method (e.g. `@Get()`, `Post()`, etc) in NestJS and the framework will take care of the rest: HTTP code, JSON, etc.

From your controller consider ditching the `@Reponse res` and using `throw new UnauthorizedException('User Not Found')` and a simple `return { token }` (or similar) approach instead.

In your protected route I have found that explicitly declaring `AuthGuard('jwt')` works better and doesn't produce warnings in certain cases, even if you did set your default strategy to be JWT.

Do you actually need the `AuthGuard('local')` on your login route?

Inside your `loginAsync()` method DO NOT forget the crucial step of actually signing your token with your payload. You didn't provide your code for the `createToken()` method implementation in your authentication service, but I suspect that this may be what you're missing.

Consider this working implementation of a login service (which is simply called by it's controller's login function):

```js
  async login(authCredentialsDto: AuthCredentialsDto): Promise<{ accessToken: string }> {
    const { email, password } = authCredentialsDto

    const success = await this.usersRepository.verifyCredentials(email, password)

    if (!success) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid credentials')
    }

    // roles, email, etc can be added to the payload - but don't add sensitive info!
    const payload: JwtPayload = { email } 
    const accessToken = this.jwtService.sign(payload)

    this.logger.debug(`Generated JWT token with payload ${JSON.stringify(payload)}`)

    return { accessToken }
  }
```

Note that the `jwtService` is injected into the class via Dependency Injection by adding `private jwtService: JwtService` to the constructor params.

Also note in the above how an interface is defined for the `JwtPayload` so it is explicitly typed. This is better than using `any` as you are in your code.

Finally, if your JWT still doesn't validate, make *absolutely sure* that you are correctly using your token in Postman. Be *extremely* careful that you're not adding leading/trailing spaces, newlines, etc. I have made this mistake myself. You may want to sanity check by writing a quick JS file to try your API and make a fetch request that sets the Authorization header with value `Bearer ${token}`.

I hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Thank you. This was a great help. What was happening is that I was using a package called `jsonwebtoken` and doing something like `import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'` followed by `jwt.sign(...)`. When using the actual `JwtService` from `@nestjs/jwt`, that fixed it.

Comment: I'm glad this helped, for sure using the actual `@nestjs/jwt` is the way to go with this approach! Cheers!

Comment: Writing a quick JS file helped me find the problem. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 9):

I had the exact same problem.My problem was that JwtModule secret and JwtStrategy secretOrKey was different. Hope this might help someone stuck with this!

Comment: I have exactly same problem! Related to .env not being loaded correctly. It's the 3rd problem I've noticed related to this and still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue.

The issue in my case that the validate endpoint params where `email` and `password`,
while the nest auth documentation states that they should be `username` and `password`  as the following:

```js
  async validate(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(username, password);
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
```

Also be aware to send `username` and `password` in the body of the request.

Credits:
https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/issues/875#issuecomment-619472086

Comment: You can pass options  object to modify the property names. Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71001043/7039250

Comment: @Safi I had the same problem, thanks for noting this edge case

Comment: lol I got stuck for one hour because of this... thank you

Answer (score 5):

Mine was that I was using RS256 algorithm to sign the JWT and I had a "Invalid algorithm" error.

So I added the `"RS256"` to my `jwtStrategy` constructor so now it look like this:

```
constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {
  super({
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    ignoreExpiration: false,
    algorithms:["RS256"],
    secretOrKey: configService.get('jwtPublicKey'),
  });
}
```

Then it gave me an error complaining about "no start line" on my public key file, the error was that I had an ssh-rsa key format instead of rsa-pem format, I solved with [Get PEM file from ssh-rsa key pair](https://serverfault.com/questions/706336/how-to-get-a-pem-file-from-ssh-key-pair)

And the finally it worked.

I got all this info, putting a logger between the strategy output and the guard output, doing this [JWT Auth Guard example](https://github.com/Vivify-Ideas/nestjs-boilerplate/blob/master/src/modules/auth/jwt-guard.ts)

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer was the most useful for me!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar 401 status. My problem was that the token expiration was really short (60s). Make sure also to have a reasonable expiration period when testing jwt.

Comment: I had the same problem. Copied the code from the official documentation with '60s' :) Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, make sure you are using Form-Encoded instead of plain form. otherwise request fields will not detect and validate method wont be called by passport. make sure you are using correct payload method **(body,form-encoded,json)** something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Make Sure that inside your strategy the path of secretKey in 
secretOrKey is implemented correctly.

    
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: appConfig().appSecret,
    });
  }
 
    async validate(payload: any) {
    return { userId: payload.userId, username: payload.username };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar 401 status. My problem was that the token expiration was set to '240' I thought wrong it is 240 seconds... but not it was 240 miliseconds...
after i change to '240s' it works fine../
read more about the ['zeit/ms' format here](https://github.com/vercel/ms)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you ctrl-s Postman after setting the token. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

```
const token = await response.json()
token.accessToken
```

i didnt notice that the jwt was an object so when posting it make sure to pass it as  a jwt string

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was not sending the bearer token in my request in Postman.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the problem was that I used my own authentication values instead of the default ones

So, I explicitly specified in super which fields I use for authentication and everything worked:

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'local') {
   private readonly logger = new Logger(LocalStrategy.name)
   constructor(
      @InjectRepository(User)
      private readonly userRepository: Repository<User>,
   ) {
      super({
         usernameField: 'email',
         passwordField: 'password',
      })
   }
...
```