# NestJS' Passport Local Strategy "validate" method never called

Tags: authentication, passport.js, nestjs, passport-local, nestjs-passport

I'm trying to implement a Passport Local Strategy but the validate method is not working. When I do `@UseGuards(AuthGuard("local"))`, it automatically throws an Unauthorized Exception without going through the validate method that I wrote. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong as the documentation did the same.

Here's my **LocalStrategy** class:

```js
@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserRepository) private userRepository: UserRepository,
  ) {
    super();
  }

  async validate(credentials: string, password: string): Promise<User> {
    // this method is never called, I've already did some console.logs
    const user = await this.userRepository.findByCredentials(credentials);

    if (!user) throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid credentials');

    if (!(await argon2.verify(user.hash, password)))
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid credentials');

    return user;
  }
}
```

My **AuthModule** imports:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserRepository]), PassportModule],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Example usage:

```js
  @Post("/login")
  @UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
  async login(@Body() loginDto: LoginDto) {
    return this.authService.login(loginDto);
  }
```

Comment: what's the documentation link?

Comment: https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication

Comment: this may put you in right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62799708/nest-js-auth-guard-jwt-authentication-constantly-returns-401-unauthorized

Comment: Ohhh I think nest expects a field called username and not credentials. If I want to call it credentials I need to pass in options yo super. Thanks!

Comment: if that solves, please post an answer it would be helpful for others in the future

Comment: Yes that solves the thing. Thanks a lot @sid

Comment: @SkullCutter how do you solved your problem ? I already read the answer mentioned before, but I still have the same problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70896560/nestjs-and-passport-local-authguardlocal-validate-never-get-called

Answer (score 30):

## EDIT

After spending more time with the code and doing a deep dive myself, it's **not** the fact that the `validate` method must have parameters *named* `username` and `password`, they could be `bob` and `alice` for all that matters, but what **is** important is that your `req.body` has two properties `username` and `password`. If you do not have `req.body.username` and `req.body.password`, then you will never make it to the `validate` of the `LocalStrategy` class.

---

The `validate` method **must** have the parameters `username` and `password` **or** the parameters **must** match the `usernameField` and `passwordField` values passed to `super()` in the constructor. If they do not match, the `validate` method will not be called. I think this comes from the fact that Nest calls `validate(...args)`, but am not 100% certain.

Comment: worked. Thanks :)

Comment: I lost so much time onto this!  should exists and log or something to tell that the validate will not be called because the fields did not match

Comment: You actually can configure the fields names on the Local Strategy to be what you desire. This can be done by calling the super() and passing an options mapping object. We can pass an options object. This will customize the behavior of the passport strategy. In this example, the passport-local strategy by default expects properties called username and password in the request body. Pass an options object to specify different property names, for example: super({ usernameField: 'email' }). See the Passport documentation for more information.

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer. It nicely expatiates on [an obscure part of the NestJs documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#:~:text=We%20can%20pass%20an%20options%20object%20in%20the%20call%20to%20super()%20to%20customize%20the%20behavior%20of%20the%20passport%20strategy.%20In%20this%20example%2C%20the%20passport%2Dlocal%20strategy%20by%20default%20expects%20properties%20called%20username%20and%20password%20in%20the%20request%20body).

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify the parameters that the validate function should use by adding the following:

**It is important to add the payload object**

```
async validate(payload: {email: string, UserId: number, role: string}) {
return { userId: payload.UserId, email:payload.email, role:payload.role };
```

}

I sign the token this way:

```
async signToken(userId: number, email: string, role: string): Promise<{access_token:string}>{
        const payload = {
            UserId: userId,
            email: email,
            role: role
        }

        console.log(payload)

        const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET

        const token = await this.JwtService.signAsync(payload, {
            expiresIn: "1d",
            secret: secret
        })
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems you're missing the `LocalAuthGuard` class here. You need to create a file with this class and then..

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class LocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('local') {}
```

This will then use the local guard.

Comment: I actually did that. I just didnt include it in my question because I didnt want to overcomplicate my question